# Solving differential equation by transform with contour integral

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, contour-integration, integral-transforms, airy-functions

In my notes, I have an example for solving for the Airy function in the equation:
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-xy=0$$
So he uses the contour integral to represent the solution (with $C$ as a yet unspecified contour):
$$y(x)=\int_C  e^{zx} \ \tilde{y}(z) dz$$
Then
$$y''(x)=\int_C z^2 e^{zx}\  \tilde{y}(z) dz$$

The equation can be written as:
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-xy=\int_C dz \ (z^2-x)e^{zx}\ \tilde{y}(z)=0$$

Now I don't understand how he got the following:
$$=\Big[e^{zx}\tilde{y}(z)\Big]_{\partial C} - \int_C dz \ (z^2+\frac{d}{dz})e^{zx}\ \tilde{y}(z)=0$$

where $\partial C$ is the edge of the contour.